# Select Person with only one value in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I can't correctly write a query.
I need to select a person who has only one value in the column. For example,

```
select * (
select PersonID, sum(TotalAmount)
from  Table1
group by PersonID
HAVING sum(TotalAmount) = 0 )
where Group = A
```

It means that I would select all customers that belong to ONLY 'A' group...

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the persons with only one value, then `having count(*) = 1` comes to mind:

```
select personid
from table1
group by personid
having count(*) = 1;
```